# Is there some standard plain text format that supports commenting

Tags: comments, syntax-highlighting, plaintext, dataformat

Something like those Unicode code point listings and similar plain text lists and tables meant for easy parsing that use hashes for line comments.

I'm asking because I'd like to use syntax highlighting for such formats if text editors support it.